# How to know where and when my iphone was bought?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to look up where and when an iPhone was purchased, based only on the serial number or other unique info inside the phone?

Comment: What sort of interface might you expect? Can you narrow down what information you need to model or something that wouldn't be totally blocked due to personal privacy issues?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a public tool for looking this up. However, if you befriend an Apple Genius, I know that the system they use for creating tickets allows them to view the purchase date and sales channel it was purchased through. However, there is no way to tell direct location (i.e. Best Buy on Main Street in St. Paul), only the channel (i.e. Best Buy).

You can also deduce the purchase date yourself by going to Apple's [Check Your Service and Support Coverage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do) page. If you locate the expiration date for repair coverage, subtract a year from that to identify original purchase date. If AppleCare was purchased, subtract an extra year.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer but may help... this page has instructions that will let you determine the manufacture date of a refurbished phone (i.e. one for which you might not have a receipt).

Summary: If the serial number begins with 5, it's a refurbished phone. The third digit is the last digit of the year of manufacture (so if your serial number begins 5K3, this is a refurbished phone manufactured in 2013). The fourth and fifth digits are the week of manufacture, so 02 would be in January, 51 in December, etc.

http://www.wikihow.com/Identify-a-Refurbished-Iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

But it won't say much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac, you can download [coconutID](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutid/index.html), which lets you check your Mac's serial number as well as any other Apple device's serial number.

Answer (score -1):

You can check iPhone/iPad purchase date and contract status with this IMEI checker - www.iphoneox.com

It doesn't show where you purchased the phone, but it should show the original carrier which narrows things down substantially.

Also this checker shows whether a carrier lock is active against that device.

Comment: It is unsafe to enter your AppleID into some third party site (and perhaps marginally risky to divulge your IMEI). Perhaps you are confusing carrier lock with activation lock?

Comment: No, it shows info about activation lock.
Friend, you're wrong, this is well known and reliable checker.

Comment: So that link shows neither when the phone was purchased nor where it was purchased?

Comment: The link shows purchase date, warranty status, contract status and FMI feature status.

Comment: -1 for 3rd party site including payment info. You don't want to share your IMEI with these people as they only enter the info into Apple's site.

Comment: Could you please let me know how you can identify purchase date, FMI status and contract expiration date via Apple's site?
I really confused, I thought I've provided useful link.